# Load pictures from folder using c# based on filename criterial?

Tags: c#, image

Recently I'm working with my Application, the problem I faced is:

> How can I load image from the folder into data grid view based on file
>   date created criteria, which is the file tag.

I appreciate any help really!

the folder which contains the pictures is:
[image]

The controls which I want to load the pictures too is:

[image]

At this time the date criteria to show the image is based on the date which the file is created.

The button which to clicked to show the images is:

```
  private void btn_show_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Please try to pinpoint the specific problem you have, and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Some pointers (since your question is very broad): DataGridViews can have a column type `DataGridViewImageColumn` - use that to hold you images. `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("/your-path", "your*pattern");` will get the files you want.

Comment: Thank you for your best suggestion. I edited and able to be specific point.

Comment: please if you know the solution, just edit the line above to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you solved your question but in case you didn't here is an answer:

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    ImageList list = new ImageList();

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      GetImages();
    }

    private void GetImages()
    {
      string path = @"C:\ImgFolder";
      string[] filter = { ".bmp", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png" };
      DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
      FileInfo[] fileInfo = directoryInfo.GetFiles();

      ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();

      foreach (FileInfo fi in fileInfo.Where(f => f.CreationTime >= YourFromDateVariable && f.CreationTime <= YourToDateVariable))
        foreach (string s in filter)
          if (s == fi.Extension)
            arrayList.Add(fi.FullName);

      //adding files to image list:
      for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.Count; i++)
      {
        Image img = Image.FromFile(arrayList[i].ToString());
        list.Images.Add(img);
      }
    }
  }
```